# HERE API: How to check does (lat, lon) belong to intersection or no?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I have GPS coordinates and want to check if it's an intersection.

I'm using POST request to "https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json" with payload:

LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
37.775210, -122.419203

And I'm getting back response with
"INTERSECTION_CATEGORY": "0" - means "NOTAPPLICABLE".

But this point corresponds to a very big intersection in San Fransico.

Please see [google-map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/37%C2%B046'30.8%22N+122%C2%B025'09.1%22W/@37.77521,-122.421397,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d37.77521!4d-122.419203)

I checked many other points with the same result. So how can I check if it is an intersection or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "INTERSECTION_CATEGORY" attribute of "LINK_ATTRIBUTE" layer is using for very specific intersections. For normally intersections the "INTERSECTION_CATEGORY" is null that means no applicable.

You can recognize if a link has intersections utilize "LINK" layer by checking attributes "REF_NODE_NEIGHBOR_LINKS"/"NON_REF_NODE_NEIGHBOR_LINKS" **if one from these attributes has more than one link then it belongs to intersection**, see please example for the link 576441292 on https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/pde_get_any_link_info and see please screenshot for it [image]

Another one example to find intersections you can see on https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/find_intersection_along_route